# fill formula in Excel column and row automatically using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am in process of automating the excel report using python and stuck in this step.Any input is greatly appreciated. i have one formula which applied to Cell AN5 =(F5-B5)/F5. On excel, I would just drag the formula to the rest of the cells to all the columns(till BK) to apply the formula . Can you please tell how to do it in python like drag function in excel. i want the formula to be applied from AN5 TO AN13(vertically) and til BK5(horizontally)

If AN5=(F5-B5)/F5 then A06 = should fill with formula (G5-C5)/G5 and so on. Please help me to complete the automation. i have went through some referenced link but dint work as per this requirement.

[image]

Comment: Just build the formulae dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There r two methods to get the next column_letter:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

def get_next_column_letter_1(column_letter):
    return column_letter[:-1] + chr(ord(column_letter[-1]) + 1)
```

Or

```
def get_next_column_letter_2(column_letter):
    return column_letter[:-1] + chr(ord(column_letter[-1]) + 1)
```

Or u can loop it directly:

```
for row in range(5, 14):
    for col in range(40, 64):
        formulas = "=({}{}-{}{})/{}{}".format(get_column_letter(col-34),
                                          row,
                                          get_column_letter(col-38),
                                          row,
                                          get_column_letter(col-34),
                                          row)
        ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = formulas
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shin..it is working as per my requirement . can you please help me to concat "pts" word to formula. i have to make  formula as                                                   formulas = formulas + ' ' + 'pts'. i tried to do it this way but it dint work for me .         formulas = "=({}{}-{}{})*100({})".format(get_column_letter(col-34),row,get_column_letter(col-38),row ,"pts" ) . can you plese help me to get that word in the formula .

Comment: @Pooja What do u mean？ The formula is like：`=(F5-B5)*100(pts)`?

Comment: as of now after applying formula i am getting 11 but i should show as 11 pts . in excel i am formatting the cell with custom formula , but how could i do here to get pts infront of numbers? i tried (F5-B5)*100(pts) but if i apply pts in the formula my excel sheet is getting corrupted . please help